# Log transforming predictor variables in survival analysis

Tags: survival-analysis

I am running shared gamma frailty models (i.e., Coxph survival analysis models with a random effect) and want to know if it is "acceptable" to log transform one of your continuous predictor variables. I found a website (http://www.medcalc.org/manual/cox_proportional_hazards.php) that said "The Cox proportional regression model assumes ... there should be a linear relationship between the endpoint and predictor variables. Predictor variables that have a highly skewed distribution may require logarithmic transformation to reduce the effect of extreme values. Logarithmic transformation of a variable var can be obtained by entering LOG(var) as predictor variable".

I would really appreciate a second opinion from someone with more statistical knowledge on this topic. In a nutshell: Is it OK/commonplace/etc to transform (specifically log transform) predictor variables in a survival analysis model (e.g., Coxph model).

Thanks.

Comment: you may find this somewhat useful http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can log transform any predictor in Cox regression. This is frequently necessary but has some drawbacks.

Why log transform? There are a number of good reasons why. You decrease the extent and effect of outliers, data becomes more normally distributed etc.

When possible? I doubt that there are circumstances when you can not do it. I find it hard to believe that it would compromise the precision of your estimates.

Why not do it always? Well it becomes difficult to interpret the results for a predictor which have been log transformed. If you don't log transform, and your predictor is, for example, blood pressure and you obtain a hazard ratio of 1.05, meaning a 5% increase in risk of event for 1 unit increase in blood pressure. IF you log transform blood pressure, the hazard ratio of 1.05 (it would most likely not land on 1.05 again after log transform but we'll stick to 1.05 for simplicity) means 5% increase for each log unit increase in blood pressure. Now thats more difficult to grasp.

But, if you are not interested in the particular variable that you think about log transforming (i.e you just need to adjust for it as a covariate), go ahead do it.

Comment: This is exactly the information/confirmation I was seeking. Thank you for such a thorough and clear explanation.

Comment: If the distribution contains zeros then log transforming is not recommended. Square root transformations can deal with zeros.